# "SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE" mode lock in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, locking

I have the following function, that is used by multiple processes at the same time. But I am getting a duplicate error sometimes in the insert operation. I thought it was a problem with the lock so I changed to a ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock, but it's no good since it locks the entire table. With the SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE mode seems that it's working, but I have some doubts about performance and access. Other processes will be able to access the table? This lock is slower in comparison to the previous one (ROW EXCLUSIVE)?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_id(...) AS $$
BEGIN
LOCK table IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;

-- select next available id
SELECT
    max(id) + 1
INTO
    o_id
FROM
    table
WHERE
    id = i_id;

-- insert id
INSERT INTO
    table
    (id)
VALUES
    (o_id);

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: "max(id)+1 ... where id=i_id" makes no sense.  Where is i_id coming from?  How is it different from o_id=i_id+1?

Comment: Hello @jjanes, I removed some parts of the code to post here. The point I'm trying to make is that I'm querying a table to get the next available id (the first select) and inserting this value in the same table. I know that doesn't make much sense the way it is. But what I need to avoid is concurrent inserts in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All locks are the same "speed". All that matters is what else they block.

In this case, what you need is an `EXCLUSIVE` lock. That blocks concurrent insert/update/delete, but not `SELECT`.

Personally, I'd do away with this idea entirely. Don't try to implement gap-less sequences in your database. Instead, generate them on demand when querying using the `row_number()` window function.